# Two datasets issues in ssrs?

Tags: reporting-services, dataset

I have a column name 'APPs % of total' and it requires two different data sets to be populated .This doesn't seem to work. Any tips will be appreciated. Thanks

```
=(Fields!AppQty.Value/Fields!AppQty.Value,"second dataset")
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is: how does SSRS know which row to pull from the second dataset to get the field? So you have to use aggregation or lookups:

**Method 1: Simply aggregate at the current level**

There's usually no need for a secondary dataset just for your sums. You can aggregate at the group level within the current dataset by using the following formula:

```
=Fields!AppQty.Value / SUM(Fields!AppQty.Value, "table1_Group1")
```

where `table1_Group1` is the group where the data is summarised.

**Method 2: Aggregate the entire dataset**

Aggregate at the dataset level for the either the current dataset or a secondary one:

```
=Fields!AppQty.Value / SUM(Fields!AppQty.Value, "SomeDataset")
```

**Method 3: Lookup the value from another dataset**

You'll need a dataset that sums the values at a group level. You usually achieve this result using method 1 and grouping, but here for completeness. So, let's say you are grouping by `DepartmentId`, you would have a dataset that aggregates like so:

```
SELECT DepartmentId, SUM(AppQty) AS AppQty
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY DepartmentId
```

Then lookup the appropriate value for the department from the current row (in the current table's dataset):

```
=Fields!AppQty.Value / Lookup(Fields!DepartmentId.Value, Fields!DepartmentId.Value, Fields!AppQty.Value, "SummaryDataset")
```

So the `Lookup` matches the `DepartmentId` from this dataset with the `DepartmentId` in the `SummaryDataset` and returns the `AppQty` value.